# Disable x-frame-options in MVC3 or IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, iframe, web-config, x-frame-options

I want to disable x-frame-options in my website, I want that no other website can show my webpages in their web pages using iframes. My website is made in ASP.net MVC3 and hosted in IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to go about this. But one of the easiest is adding `<customHeaders>` section to the web.config and it will append that header to each request.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
         </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: so this way, no one will be able to show my webpages in their website? and if I want to show my site's page in iframe on another page of the site, will it work?

Comment: @ArbazAbid For the specifics of `X-Frame-Options` you may want to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options or similar articles to pick which value is right for your situation.

Comment: I needed SAMEORIGIN value, not its working fine, thanks again

Comment: @StevenV Shoudln't I be able to see the X-Frame-Option param in header through fiddler? I used this and can't see the header entry. What's wrong (MVC 2)

Comment: @Maxsteel You definitely should. Do you have any security software or devices on your computer or network that could be stripping out the header?

Comment: @stevenV It's a stabdard corporate laptop with antivirus and whatnot but i dont think they are stripping anything from header especially something crucial for security like this. Any other reason? Or probably a way to check this?